# Bootstrap toggle nav not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My toggle navigation doesn't work, when I added elements to the right. When I scale the page, menu on the right side at the top doesn't appear. If there are no items on the right side, there is no problem.
My html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>Broker</span>tain</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#brokerbattle">Brokerbattle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#brokerbrain">Brokerbrain</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#1x2">1x2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <p class="btn">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default regist"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Registration</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="btn">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default login"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Login</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Search brokertain...">
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

JSFiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/j55ejLxh/)

Comment: The navigation collapse is a javascript function. Can you provide some more information? Perhaps place your javascript, css and HTML in a jsFiddle or some similar solution in order for anyone trying to help to see the entire relationship.

Comment: I added JSFiddle on the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/ej74xxq2/4/)** It works Fine.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Application</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-left">

                  <li><a href="#brokerbattle">Brokerbattle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#brokerbrain">Brokerbrain</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1x2">1x2</a></li>



                <li>
                    <p class="btn">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default regist"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Registration</a>
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="btn">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Login</a>
                    </p>
                </li>       
          </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search brokertain...">
</div>
    </div></nav>
```